# How to use a responsive text form field widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm using "maxLine" as a length for the text form field but it does not fit in different size of phones, what should I put in order to make the length responsive.
The box border should fit on the size of the phone.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wisa6.png. Here's my code, I'm using onTap in gesture detector to call that widget

```
Widget buildDescription() => TextFormField(
        maxLines: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toInt(),
        initialValue: widget.description,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Tell us what you feel',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                    width: 2,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid))),
        validator: (description) => description != null && description.isEmpty
            ? "I'm here to listen. Don't hesitate to open up when you're ready"
            : null,
        onChanged: widget.onChangedDescription,
      );
}
```

Comment: What would you like to happen?

Comment: I want to have a border box according to the size of the phone

Comment: What do you mean? Would you like to cut all text which does not fit in the screen?

Comment: check the image

Comment: I've added an answer. BTW you should add some example code to your question.

Comment: please simplify your example and make it complete

Comment: I just need the box border to fit in different size of phone screen.

Comment: My code should work, i just tested it in Dartpad. You need to post a more complete example for  people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should make the `TextFormField` fill the screen and also make the number of lines unlimited.

```dart
Expanded(
  child: TextFormField(
    maxLines: null,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
    expands: true,
  ),
)
```

Comment: it causes error when I'm using expanded widget, it only shows a blank scaffold

Comment: please simplify your example and make it complete, adding MaterialApp, Scaffold etc

Comment: you can use https://dartpad.dev to experiement and create a simple example

Comment: I can't upload the whole code cos it has diff functions and it's too long

Comment: Then you should make a new minimal example to show what you want. If you did that maybe you would figure out what was wrong.

Comment: The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
lib\…\diaryScreens\add_edit_IU.dart:25
 Exception caught by scheduler library 
'package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 334 pos 12: '!_debugMouseTrackerUpdateScheduled': is not true.


════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#c8056 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'
This shows in debug console when I'm opening the expanded widget

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `TextFormField` inside an `Expanded` widget, which will stretch it over the remaining screen space.

```dart
// expanded should be used inside rows or columns
return Column(
  children: [
    DateMarker(...),
    HowDidIFailField(...),
    // the expanded stretches the view over the remaining space
    Expanded(
      child: TextFormField(),
    ),
  ]
);
```

A thing to note is that when the keyboard appears, less space is available and the widget will shrink further. Make sure to test with that as well.